# Which has better performance, Enum or Int in a switch case?

Tags: c#, casting, enums, switch-statement

Which code snippet is better to use when considering the performance for the switch case with enum and int as the case parameter:

**A.**

```
switch ((ToolbarButton)BtnId)
{
    case ToolbarButton.SHOWPROPERTYDIALOG:
         OnShowProperties();
         break;
    case ToolbarButton.MOVETOFIRST:
         OnFirstMessage();
         break;
    case ToolbarButton.MOVETOLAST:
         OnLastMessage();
         break;
}
```

**B.**

```
switch (BtnId)
{
     case (int)ToolbarButton.SHOWPROPERTYDIALOG:
          OnShowProperties();
          break;
     case (int)ToolbarButton.MOVETOFIRST:
          OnFirstMessage();
          break;
     case (int)ToolbarButton.MOVETOLAST:
          OnLastMessage();
          break;
}
```

Comment: The default underlying type of an enum is `int` anyway.

Comment: I usually find network or database connections to be the performance bottleneck in my applications, rather than the type of my switch statements.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Once compiled, `Enums` ***ARE*** `Ints`.

There is No difference what-so-ever in the MSIL.

Answer (score 3):

When compiling, the JIT replaces Enums with Int32 type. This is known as inline replacement and hence there is no performance hit.  I would prefer using Enums as they increase readability and can be back-tracked (Find Reference) as well.